# Getting INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK on Genymotion device when deploying a nativescript app

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to deploy a basic wizard generated nativescript app (crossCommunicator)  to Genymotion device and get the above error. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of crossCommunicator; I can tell you that it builds fine under NativeScript 2.1, I tested both the Chapter 4 & Chapter 5 android versions tonight.

If I had to guess based on your error your issue is that you have a NativeScript version mismatch.

Type:
**tns info**

It should show something like this:
[image]

On my windows box, I don't have tns-ios installed; but if I was running this on my mac; it would have a current version.   Typically you want all these versions to match.

So to upgrade NativeScript CLI you type:

> **npm install -g nativescript@latest**

To upgrade the tns-core-modules you type:

> **npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save**

To upgrade the android platform I recommend you do:

> **tns platform remove android**
>
> **tns platform add android**

To upgrade the iOS platform I recommend you do:

> **tns platform remove iOS**
>
> **tns platform add iOS**

Comment: Hi I see the following :
$ tns info
All NativeScript components versions information
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information      │
│ nativescript     │ 2.1.0           │ 2.1.0          │ Up to date       │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.1.0           │ 2.1.0          │ Up to date       │
│ tns-android      │ 2.1.1           │ 2.1.1          │ Up to date       │
│ tns-ios          │ 2.0.1           │ 2.1.0          │ Update available │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────

Comment: If you type "tns doctor" in the project folder what does it say?